# Create varnish configuration GUI with python

Tags: python, user-interface, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is that anyway to create varnish configuration GUI with python ? I want to make my own varnish configuration GUI but I'm confuse how to edit the .vcl file with python.

Comment: Have a look at Varnish Agent 2 (https://github.com/varnish/vagent2). It enables you to edit the VCL via a GUI.

Comment: @Arjan yeah but I want to make a vcl user interface so user no need to code the vcl. Is there any way ? thx arjan,

Comment: In essence the VCL file is nothing else then a plain text file. So IMHO editing the file shouldn't be the most difficult part. I think it's more challenging to catch all the features of a programming language (which VCL is) in a GUI.

Comment: hhmm yeah I think it shouldn't be difficult. But for user that no have programming experience could be difficult to coding the vcl. Did you know how to edit vcl via php/python or another programming languange ? please help for my thesis, @Arjan